# The proper uses of a print writer and file writer

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io, filewriter, printwriter

why should we use file writer and then wrap it with a print writer when we can directly use a print writer? and we use buffered readers so they can read large chunks of data at once but then to get the output printed we have to loop them into a while loop why don't we have a simpler way to get the output printed?

Comment: Who tell you that you `should ... use file writer and then wrap it with a print writer`?

Comment: well, then does that mean there is no such need? that's how my teacher sounded yesterday when she taught about print writers. may be I got it all wrong. thank you.

Comment: One is for sure `there is no such need` in general. Exceptions are possible. ;-) Have a look at my answer for a more detailed example to show differences.

Comment: What exactly is your objection to loops, or your vision of a solution without them?

Comment: no objection, actually to get one line as output we used readLine(), so I thought there must be some code as such for reading the whole document and giving it as an output that's all, and of course using loops is not something complicated but I thought may be I am unaware of any particular code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first have a look at the javadoc for the main differences.

[FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

> Convenience class for writing character files. The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding ... FileWriter is meant for writing streams of characters.

[PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

> Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream.

Which means `FileWriter` focuses on character-wise output and you cannot define the character encoding. Whereas `PrintWriter` focuses on formatted text output and you can specify the character encoding.

Find a small example as demonstraction

```
// we need this as there is no convenient method to output a platform
// specific line separator charcater(s)
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/tmp/fw.txt")) {
    fw.append('\u2126').append(newLine);
    fw.write(65);
    fw.append(newLine);
    fw.append(String.format("%10s: %s%n", "some", "value"));
    fw.append("some line").append(newLine);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("something failed: " + ex.getMessage());
}
// the println() methods will append the right platform specific line separator
// charcater(s)
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("/tmp/pw.txt", "UTF8")) {
    pw.append('\u2126');
    pw.println();
    pw.write(65);
    pw.println();
    pw.printf("%10s: %s%n", "some", "value");
    pw.println("some line");
} catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

If you run the snippet on a unicode aware machine (or run the code as `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...`) the output will be

fw.txt

```
Ω
A
      some: value
some line
```

pw.txt

```
Ω
A
      some: value
some line
```

For the above examples the code and the result look more or less the same. `PrintWriter` provide methods for formatted output, whereas for `FileWriter` you have to do the formatting before the output.

But the big difference comes, when your environment is not unicode aware (or run the code as `java -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 ...`)

fw.txt

```
?
A
      some: value
some line
```

The unicode omega character cannot be printed with ISO8859-1 encoding.

With the `PrintWriter` we defined the character encoding for the output. Which is independent from the default encoding of the environment.

pw.txt

```
Ω
A
      some: value
some line
```

Back to your question. Wrapping a `FileWriter` into a `PrintWriter`. It is possible. But you loose the main benefit, the ability to choose the chracter encoding.

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("/tmp/pwfw.txt"))) {
    pw.append('\u2126');
    pw.println();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("something failed: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

The file `pwfw.txt` will contain the unicode character omega only if the default encoding of the environment is unicode. So you would have the same limitation (for the encoding) like with `FileWriter`.

If you have to use `FileWriter` or `PrintWriter` depends on your needs. I believe `PrintWriter` should to do it most of the time.

Comment: Thank you! I am completely clear now. thanks again for the illumination. some times small things keeps nagging in your head that you can't move ahead to other chapters the above was one of them.

Comment: @vidya You're welcome. It was my pleasure. It's not a shame to ask questions (even it might look as a simple one to some other), but (in my opinion) it's a mistake to stop learning. ;-)